# I'm getting an undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass | Trying to add posts to users profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, posts

I'm struggling with my rails app since I'm trying to add the posts from the users on their profile page.
I'm using device and I've looked online for a solution, but none seems to be working.

I'm running a Rails server 5.2.

Here are a few bits of my code :

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This is the `users.controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @posts = current_user.posts
  end

end
```

and my `posts_controller.rb` :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
```

This is the `users/show.html.erb`

```
<%= @user.about %>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

It's seems not to work since I'm having this specific error :
**undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**

```
<%= @user.about %>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you share your application_controller.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you find the solution, here is the suggestion instead.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @posts = current_user.posts
  end
end
```

Change it to

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @posts = current_user.posts
  end
end
```

- Added `before_action :authenticate_user!` in order to get current user, in most case user need to log in in order to view/edit their profile, therefore we should require user to log-in
- Changed to `@user = current_user` because now logged-in user is the user object that we need to show or edit

Answer (score 2):

You grab the `@user` in your show, but then you use `current_user.posts` to set the `@posts`.  That should probably be `@user.posts`

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
after doing a little `rake db:migrate` & restarting the server, everything seems to work. Didn't change anything.